# I can't start project without activation

Tags: python, django

I'm a new student of python django framework.
I saw most of video in YouTube that they can start project without use these commands

```
py -m venv project-name
project-name\Scripts\activate.bat
```

But when i tried. It's not working for me:

**'django-admin' is not recognized**

Comment: You are activating a virtual environment. That is a typical step to execute code in a Python project. In general it is better practice to use virtual environment per project to separate the dependencies. But it is possible to work without them (and may get problems later).

Answer (score 1):

A virtual environment is a different one from the one installed on the machine. So you will need to install what is needed again in the virtual machine. That means you need to install django again after activate.bat:

```
pip install Django
```

then django-admin is available.